# Understanding the statement of a corollary from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra third edition

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, definition, extension-field

The following corollary is on page number 572 in the 14th chapter Galois Theory:

> **Corollary 10.** Let $K/F$ be any finite extension. Then $$|Aut(K/F)| \le [ K : F ] $$ with equality if and only if  $F$ is the fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$. Put another way, $K/F$ is Galois if and only if $F$ is the fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$.

The following is definition of $Aut(K/F)$ from the book on page number 558:

> **Definition.** Let $K/F$ be an extension of fields. Let $Aut(K/F)$ be the collection of automorphisms of $K$ which fix $F$.

The definition of *fixed field* is given on page number 560 as:

> **Definition.** If $H$ is a subgroup of the group of automorphisms of $K$, the subfield of $K$ fixed by all the elements of $H$ is called the *fixed field* of $H$.

The above corollary belongs to the theorem which is given on page number 570:

> **Theorem 9.** Let $G=\{\sigma_1 =1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_n \}$ be a subgroup of automorphisms of a field $K$ and let $F$ be the fixed field. Then $$[K:F]=n=|G|.$$

Coming back to the corollary, if **by definition of $Aut(K/F)$** the group $Aut(K/F)$ has elements which fix $F$ then why "...if and only if $F$ is the fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$" is included in the statement?
(Note: It is proven in the book that $Aut(K/F)$ is a group.)

Also all the elements of $Aut(K/F)$ fix $F$ so **by definition of fixed field**, $F$ is the fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$.
So isn't it that $|Aut(K/F)|=[K:F]$ straight away?

Comment: All the elements of $Aut(K/F)$ fix $F$, but if the extension is not Galois, more might be fixed by everything. As an example, try computing $Aut(\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})/\Bbb Q)$.

Comment: @Stahl Agreed! But are the definitions given in the book bit loose? As in shouldn't the *fixed field* in the statement of corollary be the *maximal fixed field* ? Also the statement of **Theorem 9** also makes things confusing.

Comment: $F$ is not necessarily **the** fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$. As Stahl explained, the fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$ is sometimes larger than $F$. I don't see anything loose in the definitions. The definition of $Aut(K/F)$ doesn't say anything about whether some elements of $K\setminus F$ might also be fixed by those automorphisms. Theorem 9 and Corollary 10 are using the definition of the fixed field you also gave.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see. Thank you both. Actually I'm studying Galois Theory on my own and English is not my first language. So I get confused often over the statements.